# Is that possible to have two classes in the same time in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Hi I am transferring html code to php code, but i get some problems.

For example in html I am using `<ul div class="country city">...</ul>`, it contains two classes (country & city),

But when I using PHP, I need to change it to `echo "<ul div class=country city>...</ul>"` since php does not accept "" in the middle. And as a result, the system only accept the first class(country) instead of two classes.

So could I ask how to change it,
Thanks :-)

Comment: read again documentation for `echo`, learn about single and double quotes, and while at it, learn full syntax of php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use simple quote for example as HTML accept it as double quote

```
echo "<ul div class='country city'>...</ul>"
```

You can also escape your `"` so PHP can accept it:

```
echo "<ul div class=\"country city\">...</ul>"
```

Comment: why not with double quotes inside single quotes?

Comment: Or use `<<<`, or write `echo 'some code with "double quotes"'`, but note that variables wouldn't expand there and symbols wouldn't be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the quotations to make them work. like this

```
echo "<ul div class='country city'>...</ul>"
```

If you want to introduce any variable in between, you can add this by

```
echo "<ul div class='country city".$variable."'>...</ul>"
```

This is called concoction